# ArcGIS Pro Pop-ups: How do I show all attributes in rows of a single table?

Tags: arcgis-pro, popup, html, arcade

I have a pop-up configured to display a set of results for a selected location. Using Arcade expressions and HTML, I get a pop-up that looks like this:

[image]

I need to show all of the rows for each Z range instead of a single row like this:
[image]

The Arcade expressions (below) I have so far are for each chem parameter and return just the single row for each Z range.

```
//return number or a "-" instead of a <Null>
var value = $feature.Result_HxCDF
IF(value > 0){
   return text(value,'#.00000');
} else {
   return '-';
}
```

The HTML code for the pop-up is as follows:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr style="background-color:#BDB76B;">
    <th>Station ID</th>
    <th>Z range <br>(ft)</th>    
    <th>Total PCBs <br>(µg/kg)</th>
    <th>tDDx<br>(µg/kg)</th>
    <th>HxCDF<br>(µg/kg)</th>
    <th>PeCDD<br>(µg/kg)</th>
    <th>TeCDD<br>(µg/kg)</th>
    <th>tPAH<br>(µg/kg)</th> 
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: center">{Samp_ID}</td>
    <td style="text-align: center">{Sdepth_ft}-{Edepth_ft}</td>
    <td style="text-align: center; {expression/PCBscolor};">{expression/PCBsvalue} {Qual_PCBs}</td>
    <td style="text-align: center; {expression/tDDxcolor};">{expression/tDDxvalue} {Qual_tDDx}</td>
    <td style="text-align: center; {expression/HxCDFcolor};">{expression/HxCDFvalue} {Qual_HxCDF}</td>
    <td style="text-align: center; {expression/PeCDDcolor};">{expression/PeCDDvalue} {Qual_PeCDD}</td>
    <td style="text-align: center; {expression/TeCDDcolor};">{expression/TeCDDvalue} {Qual_TeCDD}</td>
    <td style="{expression/tPAHfont}; text-align: center; {expression/tPAHcolor};">{expression/tPAHvalue} {Qual_tPAH}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How do I adjust the code to get the full table?

Comment: So are you saying that your station ID's might be different ID's but are spatially the same point location? If so you might be better off restructuring your data into a 1:Many related table and extracting your information that way. That will pay dividends in the long run...

Comment: Yes. The station ID's change because each sample is collected at a different depth.

Comment: All of the data are in the same attribute table so there is no way to do the join right? Would it be better solved by grouping by location?

Comment: You could create a query view (or a database view) that does the join, instead of doing an ArcGIS Join on the layer.  A database view is fine with multiple references to the same table.

Comment: My data is in an imported table not an external DB. I have tried all of your suggestions to no avail. Could someone please show me how to adjust the code above to achieve my desired stated results?